# How can you keep, on SVN, the reference to its original location on a folder/file when moving it?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I've created a feature branch to work in parallel with the trunk.

In the brach I've done a big amount of structure (folder) changes. For example, I've moved folders that before were on:

```
application/views/scripts/users/*
```

to:

```
application/modules/user/views/scripts/users/*
```

Now, I'm trying to do a merge from the trunk to this feature branch and I'm founding a million of tree conflicts! And the issue is that since this tree conflicts appear, no file inside that tree is merged against anything.

I mean, I find a tree conflict on:

```
application/views/scripts/users (SVN message: "The last merge operation tried to modify the directory 'users', but it was deleted, moved or renamed locally")
```

and none of the files and other folders that were inside that path have been merged.

Is there a way to recover the "link" between the original location of a folder and the current one?

Can I do something to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than a solution, I can give a workaround, that is the one that I've used, becuase it seems that there's not really a solution for this.

After a little research I'm close to sure that SVN doesn't support this kind of feature for merging. In the documentation of TortoiseSVN it is said that:

> **Local missing, incoming edit upon merge**
>
> Developer A working on trunk modifies Foo.c and commits it to the
>   repository
>
> Developer B working on a branch moves Foo.c to Bar.c and commits it to
>   the repository
>
> A merge of developer A's trunk changes to developer B's branch working
>   copy results in a tree conflict:
>
> Bar.c is already in the working copy with status 'normal'.
>
> Foo.c is marked as missing with a tree conflict.
>
> **To resolve this conflict**, Developer B has to mark the file as resolved
>   in the conflict editor dialog, which will remove it from the conflict
>   list. She then **has to decide** whether to copy the missing file Foo.c
>   from the repository to the working copy, whether to merge Developer
>   A's changes to Foo.c into the renamed Bar.c or whether to ignore the
>   changes by marking the conflict as resolved and doing nothing else.

This means that you have to decide, one tree conflict at a time, what to do. And this is not the worst part. What is really unacceptable in my case is that every time I do a new merge from the trunk to this branch I'll be forced to deal with this conflicts again.

## The workaround

Replicate the structural changes made on the branch into the trunk (with its required changes on code) and make it work with them.

After commiting this changes both structures of files, the trunk and the branch will match, so later merge operation won't complain anymore.

Answer (score -1):

What i understand from your issue is that you have done a lot of folder structural changes in your branch and since these changes are not there in your trunk and when you are trying to merge you are getting the error.

As per your statement, "Now, I'm trying to do a merge from the trunk to this feature branch"

At the first place when you have taken a branch out from your trunk and did the structural changes in your branch then you should merge these changes from "branch to trunk" or if you simply want to get the original structure ("recover the original location of folders")back then just revert the changes you have done in the branch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ankit, but is not exactly that. I don't want to "recover the original location of folders" but to keep the relation between the folders (and files) that were moved. When I try to do the merge, all the files that were moved are not merged due to "tree conflicts", because SVN seems to not be aware of the relation between the file located in the trunk and the pair (moved) in the branch.

Comment: Sorry for getting your question wrong. I have found some data related to tree conflicts at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html. Please see if this can help.

Comment: Hi Roberto, the same workaroud i was trying to mention in my post above "you should merge these changes from "branch to trunk"".

Comment: Hi Ankit, I thought that you were telling to do a whole merge from the branch to the trunk. And this is not what I suggest on the workaround that I've posted. I have, already, many changes (not structural) on the branch and I don't want to pollute the trunk with this changes. I was telling just to replicate the structural changes on the trunk, so later commits wont find tree conflicts due to non matching source-destination of files.